# Tipos de datos en parametros

Tags: java, retrofit, parametros, tipos

Mi pregunta es corta, tengo dos funciones, la primera es:

```
public ResponseEntity<Object> aFunction(Call<ClaseA> a){
    try{
          a.execute().body().getContent();
    }catch(Exception e){
          System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

La segunda función tiene la misma lógica pero el tipo de dato del parámetro es de otra clase, cómo puedo unificar eso en una función para no tener codigo repetido?
hay alguna forma de especificar que el dato puede ser de tipo a o b como en otros lenguajes más actuales?

PD: Estoy usando Java 11 con Retrofit y si uso el tipo de dato Object me sale error al llamar la función execute, body y getContent

Comment: En mi App Android yo opté por una clase envoltorio, definida así: `public class DataWrapper<T, E extends CustomException> {` con ella recibo: o las respuestas de Retrofit o de Firebase mapeadas en el parámetro `T` que puede ser cualquier clase de mi modelo de datos, o una Exception en el parámetro `E`. Así, desde distintas fuentes de datos, puedo usar `DataWrapper` para las llamadas y, en el caso de Android meterla también en un LiveData para observar los cambios en la vista. Creo que algo así podría servirte.

Comment: Desde cualquier contexto, tú puedes entonces hacer esto: `DataWrapper<UnaClase, CustomException> unaClase` y usar esa instancia para recibir una respuesta que aquí será del tipo `UnaClase` o si ocurre error, echas mano de `CustomException`, y en otro contexto puedes hacer esto:  `DataWrapper<OtraClase, CustomException> otraClase` ... y así sucesivamente. A mí me funciona muy bien en Android / Retrofit (o Firebase) / RXJava  y aplicando el patrón MVVM que implica usar `LiveData`, lo interesante es que en la respuesta puedo saber si hubo error también e informar al usuario.

Comment: me funcionó, muchas gracias @A.Cedano